# I can't get any mods working!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mods

I can't get any mods working! I can download the mods just fine. I always drop them into my "mods folder" and everything seems to be going okay, but every time I boot up minecraft it just goes on normally as if I hadn't downloaded any mods at all! It doesn't even crash! What am I doing wrong? I already installed Forge to "teach" minecraft to recognise mods but it's not working either...

Comment: I assume they are Forge Mods of some sort.. Have you run the Forge installer for 1.6+??? Its not as simple as drag and drop any more to get that part done.. The rest of the mods are though.. and then you have to make sure you selected the right profile to run Forge instead of a vanilla jar file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular Minecraft doesn't know what mods are, so it will completely ignore your mods folder and never do anything with any files you put in there unless you "teach" it to look there, and what to do with the files it finds.

The usual "teaching" method is by installing Forge, which is exactly designed to teach Minecraft to look for and load stuff you put in the mods folder (among other things relevant only to mod-makers).

[Installing Forge is really simple](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Universal):

1. [Download it.](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) Choose the "Recommended" build for your version of Minecraft, and click the "installer" link.
2. Run the installer.
3. In the Minecraft launcher, choose the new profile named "Forge" or similar and click **Play**.

If you want greater explanation of how the installation process works, you can read the [Installation](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Universal) article on the Forge Wiki.

Comment: Bah, expand my comment into an answer will ya.. You will just have to take this +1 and like it!

Comment: @James Thanks. ;) I've been doing a lot of work with Forge and multiple custom profiles (private modpack dev and maintenance), so this stuff is very familiar now!

Comment: I have forge, and I have it selected on my profile, and it still doesn't work. however I do not have the actual forge account selected. does the actual forge account have to be selected for it to work?

Comment: You can either use the profile that Forge created for you, or you can edit another profile's "Use version" option and select the Forge version it installed. Both have the same effect of telling the launcher to use the jar file that contains Forge modifications. If it's not working, then you have a different problem. Can you please add to the question (or link to it on pastebin) a copy of `ForgeModLoader-client-0.log`? You should find it in your .minecraft folder, beside your mods folder.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The mods are working now! Thanks a lot!